# Does ActiveMQ Artemis support updating scheduled messages in a last value queue?

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

In my testing and review of the Artemis [LastValueQueue code](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/a30c37aaccc91aaaeb04200c5071249b5528ba07/artemis-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/server/impl/LastValueQueue.java#L165), it looks like the scheduling delay for a message takes precedence over its evaluation of the "last-value-key".  In other words, if you schedule a message, it is only evaluated for replacing the last-value in the queue at the time it is prepared for delivery.

My question is whether I have correctly understood the code, and if so, if there's a workaround or a feature of ActiveMQ / Artemis that might help meet our requirements.

Our requirements are as follows:

1. Generate a message, and delay processing of that message to a point in the future (usually 30 seconds out).
2. If an updated version of the message is generated due to a new external event, replace any existing scheduled message with the new version of the message - the scheduled delivery time should also be updated, in addition to the message payload.

Some other notes:

- My current prototype is using Artemis embedded server
- Spring-jms JmsTemplate is being used to produce messages
- Spring-jms JmsListenerContainerFactory is being used to consume messages
- We don't currently use SpringBoot, so you'll see some bean setup below.

**ArtemisConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class ArtemisConfig {

    @Bean
    public org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.Configuration configuration() throws Exception {
        org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.Configuration config = new ConfigurationImpl();
        config.addAcceptorConfiguration("in-vm", "vm://0");
        config.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        config.setSecurityEnabled(false);
        config.setJournalType(JournalType.ASYNCIO);
        config.setCreateJournalDir(true);
        config.setJournalDirectory("/var/mq/journal");
        config.setBindingsDirectory("/var/mq/bindings");
        config.setLargeMessagesDirectory("/var/mq/large-messages");
        config.setJMXManagementEnabled(true);

        QueueConfiguration queueConfiguration = new QueueConfiguration("MYLASTVALUEQUEUE");
        queueConfiguration.setAddress("MYLASTVALUEQUEUE");
        queueConfiguration.setLastValueKey("uniqueJobId");
        queueConfiguration.setDurable(true);
        queueConfiguration.setEnabled(true);
        queueConfiguration.setRoutingType(RoutingType.ANYCAST);

        CoreAddressConfiguration coreAddressConfiguration = new CoreAddressConfiguration();
        coreAddressConfiguration.addQueueConfiguration(queueConfiguration);

        config.addAddressConfiguration(coreAddressConfiguration);

        return config;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedActiveMQ artemisServer() throws Exception {
        EmbeddedActiveMQ server = new EmbeddedActiveMQ();
        server.setConfiguration(configuration());
        server.start();

        return server;
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() throws Exception {
        artemisServer().stop();
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory activeMqConnectionFactory() throws Exception {
        return ActiveMQJMSClient.createConnectionFactory("vm://0", "artemis-client");
    }


    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsListenerContainerFactory() throws Exception {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(activeMqConnectionFactory());
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        factory.setConcurrency("8");
        factory.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws Exception {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(activeMqConnectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
        jmsTemplate.setDeliveryPersistent(true);

        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    QueueMessageService queueMessageService() {
        return new QueueMessageService();
    }
}
```

**QueueMessageService.java**

```
public class QueueMessageService {
    @Resource
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public void queueJobRequest(
            final String queue,
            final int priority,
            final long deliveryDelayInSeconds,
            final MyMessage message) {

        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, jobRequest, message -> {
            message.setJMSPriority(priority);
            if (deliveryDelayInSeconds > 0 && deliveryDelayInSeconds <= 86400) {
                message.setLongProperty(
                        Message.HDR_SCHEDULED_DELIVERY_TIME.toString(),
                        Instant.now().plus(deliveryDelayInSeconds, ChronoUnit.SECONDS).toEpochMilli()
                );
            }
            message.setStringProperty(Message.HDR_LAST_VALUE_NAME.toString(), "uniqueJobId");
            message.setStringProperty("uniqueJobId", jobRequest.getUniqueJobId().toString());
            return message;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding about the semantics of scheduled messages with a last-value queue is correct. When a message is scheduled it is not technically *on the queue* yet. It is not put onto the queue until the scheduled time arrives at which point last-value queue semantics are enforced.

Short of implementing a new feature I don't see how you can implement your desired behavior in any kind of automatic way. My recommendation at this point would be to use the management API (i.e. `QueueControl`) to manually remove the "old" scheduled message before you send the "new" scheduled message. You can use one of the `removeMessage` methods for this as they will work on scheduled messages and non-scheduled messages alike.

Comment: And what would be the outcome if 5 different messages have the same `_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY` timestamp and the same `_AMQ_LVQ_NAME`?

Comment: @lonely-sm-developer, please ask a new question about this. Thanks!