# What happens if 5 scheduled messages have the same _AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY and _AMQ_LVQ_NAME in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: activemq-artemis

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71051961/does-activemq-artemis-support-updating-scheduled-messages-in-a-last-value-queue/71052851) or better to say the answer to it, made me wonder what would be the outcome of the following: having 5 different messages containing exactly the same `_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY` and `_AMQ_LVQ_NAME`? Would it be only the latest one in that case delivered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ScheduledDeliveryRunnable](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.29.0/artemis-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/server/impl/ScheduledDeliveryHandlerImpl.java#L227) will iterate the 5 scheduled messages with the same _AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY and _AMQ_LVQ_NAME one at time. They will put onto the queue one at time and all of them will be delivered the connected consumers.